# Conversión explicita InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvc

Resulta, que tengo dos clases, 1 base *Cliente* y otra derivada *Persona*. La cosa es que cuando genero la acción *details*, en el controlador, me lanza el siguiente error

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Persona persona = db.Clientes.Find(id);
            if (persona == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(persona);
        }
```

P.D: Estoy trabajando en VS community 2017,  Proyecto web en `C#`.  [image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Persona persona = db.Clientes.Find(id) as Persona;
```

o

```
Persona persona = (Persona)db.Clientes.Find(id);
```

Comment: Sería bueno que le dieras a [edit] para añadir explicaciones de tu código. ¡Lee [answer]!

Answer (score 0):

A ver vamos por paso. Existen varias formas para hacer un cast. Puedes utilizar los operadores **implicit** y **explicit** para decidir como quieres que haga el cast. La forma recomendable para hacer un cast es utilizando el operador AS porque en caso de que de cualquier tipo de excepción devuelve **NULL** y no lanza ninguna excepción.

En tiempo de compilación el compilador solo entiende el valor de la izquierda así que si pones este código en el Visual Studio verás que te dice que debes poner el cast explicitamente:

```
class A{} 

class B:A{}

void Main()
{
  A objA = new B(); // Liskov
  B objB = new B();

  objA = objB; // El compilador solo entiende que el tipo de objA es A aunque hayas aplicado Liskov
}
```

En fin que son conceptos básicos que son necesarios aprender para poder trabajar con los conceptos básicos de la Programación Orientada a Objetos.